# Rails 3: How to make a join in mysql over 3 tables (with :through in the model)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

ingredient.rb:

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes, :through => :ingredients_with_quantities
  has_many :ingredients_with_quantities
```

ingredient_with_quantity.rb:

```
class IngredientWithQuantity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
```

recipe.rb:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :ingredients_with_quantities
  has_many :ingredients_with_quantities
```

I would like to make a query which get all recipes that includes a specific ingredient name.

Tried this query:

```
Recipe.find(:all, :include => {:ingredients_with_quantities => :ingredients}, :conditions => "ingredients.name = 'ingredient1'")
```

But I get this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Recipe::IngredientsWithQuantity
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong with the query?

I can make a successfull query in SQL with:

```
SELECT r . * FROM recipes r, ingredient_with_quantities iq, ingredients i 
WHERE i.name =  "ingredient1"
AND iq.recipe_id = r.id 
AND iq.ingredient_id = i.id
```

How does this query looks in Rails with ActiveRecord?

Thanks for helping me out!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `:ingredient_with_quantities` rather than `:ingredients_with_quantities` (you put a "s" after `ingredient`)

Comment: OMG...I didn't see that! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Changed the models to "has_many :ingredient_with_quantities" and the query to: 
Recipe.find(:all, :include =>{:ingredient_with_quantities => :ingredient}, :conditions => "ingredients.name = 'ingredient1'")

Comment: With rails 3 you have new nice notation like Recipe.include(:ingredient_with_quantities => :ingredient).where("ingredients.name = 'ingredient1'")  . Moreover you can have your recipes by the through with Ingredients.where("ingredients.name = 'ingredient1'").first.recipes

Comment: This notation would be nicer but both queries doesn't work. From the first I get: "NoMethodError: private method `include' called for #<Class:0xad51b78>"
Error from second query: "Could not find the association :ingredients_with_quantities in model Ingredient"

Comment: Ok i found my mistake... didn't change the "s" here... :through => :ingredients_with_quantities should be :through => :ingredient_with_quantities